# FIREBASE - How to sort data from a collection by the frequency of occurrence of the words from that data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to sort data stored in a collection by the frequency of the occurrence of the words from that data and then send it to my front-end in a form of an array of, let's say 20, most commonly used words. How can I force firebase to do that for me ;) ? Thank you in advance for any tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built into Firestore to count the frequency of words in a text. In addition, Firestore has no support for aggregation queries, where you order/filter on calculated values. All it can do, is order/filter on values that are stored in the documents that you read/query.

So if you want to be able to query on that frequency, you will have to store the frequency in a bunch of documents and query/read those.

For example, you could generate a collection where each document is a word, and in that document you then keep the count of how often that word occurrs. You can then easily find the 20 most common occurrences with:

```
wordOccurenceRef.orderBy("count", "desc").limit(20);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Correct me if I'm wrong: I create a collection of documents, every one of those documents will have 2 fields: one for a string and second one for a number. Then if the string  extracted from the front-end form already exists in some of the documents from my DB, I get this document and update the number value? How do I check if the word exists? How to update a value from a specific document? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thanks to Firestore's built-in `increment` operation, it's actually a bit simpler than that. When adding new data, loop over the words in that data, and for each word: `wordOccurenceCollectionRef.doc(word).update({ count: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) })`. If you're having trouble making this work, it's probably best to post a new question with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) though.

Comment: Thank you very much, Frank!